# How to make a date column in R show every hour in a year

Tags: r, date, missing-data

I have a dataframe of information including hourly means for individual nodes, but when there is an hour missing it just skips that row.

How can I make it so that each node has the same number of rows, ie every hour in 2022?

I've converted the dates so that they are read as such, I just need to fill in the missing rows for each node.

Comment: This question will likely be closed because it shows no effort, does not include a testing dataset or desired output (therefore not testable or reproducible), and very likely already has answers elsewhere in stackoverflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please see my package timeplyr which has two functions that will likely help: `time_expand()` and `time_complete()`.

Though without further information I'm not sure if this is what you want.

For example:

```
remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)
data %>%
  time_complete(time = time_column, node, by = "hour")
```

This will fill in the missing gaps in time for each node, using the entire range of the time variable specified.